# Is the following function coercive? Can anyone help

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Is the following function coercive?

My professor wrote:

> In the function $f(x_1, x_2) = x_1^3+x_2^2+3$, we
>   notice that the leading term $x_1$. is odd so it can’t be coercive. To
>   prove this we consider the restriction to the x-axis ((x, y) = (t, 0))
>   so we have $φ(t) = t^3 + 3$, this restriction is such that:
>
> $\lim_{t \to +∞} φ(t) =\lim_{t \to +∞} t^3 + 3 = +∞$ and  $\lim_{t \to
> > -∞} φ(t) = \lim_{t \to -∞} t^3 + 3 = −∞$ so the function can’t be coercive.

I do not understand why the fact that the restriction is such that
$\lim_{t \to +∞} φ(t) =\lim_{x \to +∞} t^3 + 3 = +∞$ and 
$\lim_{t \to -∞} φ(t) = \lim_{t \to -∞} t^3 + 3 = −∞$

Implies that the function is not coercive. Is this because this implies that the function is not bounded?

Comment: because a coercive function $\phi(t)$ has $\phi(t) \to \infty$ for $|t| \to \infty$

Comment: What's your definition of coercive?

Comment: Thank you. But why do we need to use restrictions? Couldn't we use simply 'separation of variables'?

Comment: My def of coercivity is that $\lim_{\|x\| \to \infty}f(x) = \infty$. Why this definition implies $\phi(t)$ has $\phi(t) \to \infty $for $|t| \to \infty$?

Answer (score 2):

> Here we have a function $f$
>   \begin{align*}
> &f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}\\
> &f(x_1,x_2)=x_1^3+x_2^2+3\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   from  which  we want to show that it is *not* coercive. In order to show that $f$ is not coercive a single counter-example is already sufficient.

Coercive means that  whenever we  consider $x$ with $||x||\to +\infty$ then we have $f(x)\to +\infty$. When analysing $f(x_1,x_2)$ in (1) we see that

- when we set $x_2=0$ in $f$ we have $f(x_1,0)=x_1^3+3$
- $\lim_{x_1\to -\infty}f(x_1,0)=\lim_{x_1\to-\infty}x_1^3+3=-\infty$.

> Note that this is all we need for our counter example, since $x=(x_1,0)$ with $\lim_{x_1\to -\infty}f(x_1,0)=-\infty$ implies that $\lim_{||(x_1,0)||\to\infty}f(x_1,0)=\color{blue}{-\infty}$ showing that $f$ is not coercive.

In order to make this counter-example even more obvious we can extract this special case as function by its own and consider a *restriction* $\phi$ with
\begin{align*}
&\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\\
&\phi(t)=t^3+3\\
\end{align*}
Note that $\phi(t)$ corresponds to $f(t,0)$. So, we argue as above by taking $t$ with $t\to-\infty$ showing that $\phi(t)$ is not coercive, since it implies that $\lim_{||t||\to\infty}\phi(t)=-\infty$.

Comment: Ok, now it is clear ti me. Thank you. To be more precise of we write $\lim_{||t||\to\infty}\phi(t)=-\infty$ the it may be' the case that the function is negative coercive so I think it is better to write that $\lim_{t\to -\infty}\phi(t)=-\infty$nand $\lim_{t\to\infty}\phi(t)=+\infty$

Comment: @LearningProb: You're welcome. Good to see the answer is useful. Btw, we do not say negative coercive, but *not coercive* instead. A function being coercive always means the function is going to plus infinity when the norm of $x$ is going to plus infinity.